# using a 32bit Oracle ODAC driver on 64bit SQL connection

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, oracle

I have an ODAC 32bits driver installed on my server, the 64 version doesnt work for me for whatever reason.

So i have to use this 32bit driver, which works just fine on my asp.net application... but now i cant use it to connect via sql server.

I need to make a shceduled task to extract data every day from an oracle database.

The idea here is make an **SQL Job** to extract said data. From my understanding i need a **linkedserver** to said Oracle database.

I have the linked server created, which is the following:

```
    exec master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop 'ORAOLEDB.Oracle', N'AllowInProcess', 1
exec master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop 'ORAOLEDB.Oracle', N'DynamicParameters', 1 

exec sp_addlinkedserver N'UT', 'Oracle', 'ORAOLEDB.Oracle', N'//xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/', N'FetchSize=2000', ''
exec master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'UT', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'true'

exec sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname='UT', @useself=N'FALSE', @rmtuser=N'xxxxxx', @rmtpassword='xxxxxx'
```

When it tries to connect it gives me the following error though:

```
El proveedor OLE DB de 32 bits "ORAOLEDB.Oracle" no se puede cargar en proceso en un servidor SQL Server de 64 bits.
```

Translated:

```
The OLE DB provider of 32 bits "ORAOLEDB.Oracle" can not be loaded on process in a SQL Server of 64 bits.
```

I dont know what to do from here, and im not even sure if this is the best solution for my needs either.

I dont have access to the external Oracle DB itself, only a connection string.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Offhand, it sounds like perhaps your SQL Server is 64-bit, and thus needs a 64-bit oledb driver.  Given a 64-bit OS, the question of 32-bit vs. 64-bit driver is a question of the app that is calling it.  32-bit  app and 32-bit driver, 64-bit app and 64-bit driver.

Comment: Why not use the [managed driver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/), which is entirely written in .NET and avoids all the 32 bit vs 64 bit issues?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `OPENROWSET` function. This differs from using a linked server in that the connection is made on the fly - the command requires connection information to be included in the call. The command can be fairly complex, so see the BoL documentation on the function for full details.